# Adding fields to Joomla 3.x contact component

Tags: joomla, contacts

I need to add fields to the joomla 3.x com_contact component. I have found some instructions via google search but they are all for earlier versions (i.e. 2.5) of Joomla.

I know there are other components on the extensions.joomla.org site, but they are not what I want. And I am not looking for contact form components. I don't need to create forms.

I tried adapting the 2.5 modifications I found for 3.x but they don't work. At least I could not get them to work.

Here's the closest I found to doing this. But it is for joomla 2.5 and the steps appear to be different for 3.x based on my attempts to do this.

[How to do it but apparently not for Joomla 3.x](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://www.360php.net/tutorials/27-how-to-add-custom-field-to-any-joomla-component-and-display-it-on-the-backend-joomla-16-17-25.html)

Does anyone have step-by-step directions on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The contact component has something like 10 fields, is there really a reason that you can't use one of them and just change the string?

Answer (score 6):

If you want add fields to Joomla 2.5.x/3.x ‘Contact Form’ do these steps:
(I want to add ‘**telephone**’ field)

1-  Go to *Joomla Directory > components > com_contact > models > forms*
Open ‘**contact.xml**’ file.

2-  Add this code  to the file between ‘fieldset’ element:

```
<field name="contact_telephone"
type="text"
id="contact-telephone"
size="30"
description="Your Number for Contact"
label="Phone"
filter="string"
required="true"/>
```

3-  Go to *Joomla Directory > components > com_contact > views > contact > tmpl*
Open ‘**default_form.php**’ file.

4-  Find this code in the file:

```
<legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTACT_FORM_LABEL'); ?></legend>
```

and add this code between  element:

```
<dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('contact_telephone'); ?></dt>
<dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('contact_telephone'); ?></dd>
```

5-  Go to *Joomla Directory > components > com_contact > controllers*
Open ‘**contact.php**’ file.

6-  Find ‘**_sendEmail**’ function
  [find this code: `private function _sendEmail($data, $contact)` ]
and add this code in the function:

```
$telephone  = $data['contact_telephone'];
```

and then change this code

```
$body = $prefix."\n".$name.' <'.$email.'> '."\r\n\r\n".stripslashes($body);
```

to

```
$body = $prefix."\n".$name.' ('.$email.', '.$telephone.') '."\r\n\r\n".stripslashes($body);
```

I added the variable $telephone in that line.
Now, emails contain the telephone-number from the sender.

This worked perfectly for me!

Comment: You should really avoid editing the core Joomla files.  Any future updates could wipe out any changes breaking the site.

Comment: http://icueproject.com/products/override-xml-forms  Use this plug-in in combination with the above answer and your issue of changes being wiped out due to update will no longer be a concern :)

Answer (score 0):

On Step number 4 IF YOU`RE USING A TEMPLATE, then you go to:

*Joomla Directory > templates > your_template_folder_name > html > com_contact > contact > and ppen ‘default_form.php’ file.